# java string replace whitespaces between two different special characters

Tags: java, regex

My String is `abc   \n|   \n|date 123 time`  I want is

```
abc \n|\n|date 123 time
```

How to remove the spaces between two different special characters, `|`, `\`. And that `\` slash symbol should follow immediately after the | (Pipe) symbol with multiple spaces.  Is there any regex available?

For you kind information, I want to keep the multiple spaces in my remaining part of my String. So please 123 are the spaces. I want to keep other spaces as it is in the String, and remove the spaces between the two characters, i. e  **| \ ** only.

Comment: show us your attempt!

Comment: use replace String a ="abc \n| \n|"; a.replace(" ","");

Comment: hi all kindly see question now ... need more details?

Comment: I don't see `|` after `abc` so why space after it was removed (it wasn't between `|` and `\n`)? Maybe you just want to remove spaces that are before `\n`?

Comment: no need to remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that  in your string `\n` is literal, not new-line mark you can use

```
String data="abc \\n| \\n|date 123 time";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("[|]\\s+\\\\n", "|\\\\n"));
```

This will find `|` that has one or more spaces after it and `\n`. Then will replace it with `|\n`.

Output:

```
abc \n|\n|date 123 time
```